# Can you use powershell to "spin up" new VM instances

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, powershell, hyper-v, automation

Learning powershell and working on creating VMs with Hyper-v. I was wondering is there a way or an ideal way to go about installing/setting up guest operating systems as well with it?

So far the only conclusion I have come up with would be to copy .vhd/.vhdx and attach them to the new VMs. However, I know with *nix this can cause issues with the whole network setup and requires manual fixing but I assume this would be fine Windows wise?

Edit: Yes, I am aware of cmdlets for Hyper-V. That is not what I am asking. **Is there a way to install an OS to the newly created VM**?

Comment: The question as it stands is not good.  You install an OS to a VM the same way as you install an OS to a physical box (from disc, automated deploy, cloning etc).  The question title is vague and your edit no better.  You want to 'spin up VMs using powershell' but you are 'not asking about hyper-v cmdlets'.  What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj933287.aspx for an example of creating a VM and installing an OS from scratch.

The steps are to create the vm, configure the vm, add the source ISO and a floppy with the unmattend.xml, then start the vm

Answer (score 2):

Yes. PowerShell can do a lot with Hyper-V virtual machines. Take your pick form the following CMDlets:

```
Add-VMDvdDrive
Add-VMFibreChannelHba
Add-VMHardDiskDrive
Add-VMMigrationNetwork
Add-VMNetworkAdapter
Add-VMNetworkAdapterAcl
Add-VMNetworkAdapterExtendedAcl
Add-VmNetworkAdapterRoutingDomainMapping
Add-VMRemoteFx3dVideoAdapter
Add-VMScsiController
Add-VMStoragePath
Add-VMSwitch
Add-VMSwitchExtensionPortFeature
Add-VMSwitchExtensionSwitchFeature
Checkpoint-VM
Compare-VM
Complete-VMFailover
Connect-VMNetworkAdapter
Connect-VMSan
Convert-VHD
Copy-VMFile
Debug-VM
Disable-VMEventing
Disable-VMIntegrationService
Disable-VMMigration
Disable-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter
Disable-VMResourceMetering
Disable-VMSwitchExtension
Disconnect-VMNetworkAdapter
Disconnect-VMSan
Dismount-VHD
Enable-VMEventing
Enable-VMIntegrationService
Enable-VMMigration
Enable-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter
Enable-VMReplication
Enable-VMResourceMetering
Enable-VMSwitchExtension
Export-VM
Export-VMSnapshot
Get-VHD
Get-VM
Get-VMBios
Get-VMComPort
Get-VMConnectAccess
Get-VMDvdDrive
Get-VMFibreChannelHba
Get-VMFirmware
Get-VMFloppyDiskDrive
Get-VMHardDiskDrive
Get-VMHost
Get-VMHostNumaNode
Get-VMHostNumaNodeStatus
Get-VMIdeController
Get-VMIntegrationService
Get-VMMemory
Get-VMMigrationNetwork
Get-VMNetworkAdapter
Get-VMNetworkAdapterAcl
Get-VMNetworkAdapterExtendedAcl
Get-VMNetworkAdapterFailoverConfiguration
Get-VmNetworkAdapterIsolation
Get-VMNetworkAdapterRoutingDomainMapping
Get-VMNetworkAdapterVlan
Get-VMProcessor
Get-VMRemoteFx3dVideoAdapter
Get-VMRemoteFXPhysicalVideoAdapter
Get-VMReplication
Get-VMReplicationAuthorizationEntry
Get-VMReplicationServer
Get-VMResourcePool
Get-VMSan
Get-VMScsiController
Get-VMSnapshot
Get-VMStoragePath
Get-VMSwitch
Get-VMSwitchExtension
Get-VMSwitchExtensionPortData
Get-VMSwitchExtensionPortFeature
Get-VMSwitchExtensionSwitchData
Get-VMSwitchExtensionSwitchFeature
Get-VMSystemSwitchExtension
Get-VMSystemSwitchExtensionPortFeature
Get-VMSystemSwitchExtensionSwitchFeature
Grant-VMConnectAccess
Import-VM
Import-VMInitialReplication
Measure-VM
Measure-VMReplication
Measure-VMResourcePool
Merge-VHD
Mount-VHD
Move-VM
Move-VMStorage
New-VFD
New-VHD
New-VM
New-VMReplicationAuthorizationEntry
New-VMResourcePool
New-VMSan
New-VMSwitch
Optimize-VHD
Remove-VM
Remove-VMDvdDrive
Remove-VMFibreChannelHba
Remove-VMHardDiskDrive
Remove-VMMigrationNetwork
Remove-VMNetworkAdapter
Remove-VMNetworkAdapterAcl
Remove-VMNetworkAdapterExtendedAcl
Remove-VMNetworkAdapterRoutingDomainMapping
Remove-VMRemoteFx3dVideoAdapter
Remove-VMReplication
Remove-VMReplicationAuthorizationEntry
Remove-VMResourcePool
Remove-VMSan
Remove-VMSavedState
Remove-VMScsiController
Remove-VMSnapshot
Remove-VMStoragePath
Remove-VMSwitch
Remove-VMSwitchExtensionPortFeature
Remove-VMSwitchExtensionSwitchFeature
Rename-VM
Rename-VMNetworkAdapter
Rename-VMResourcePool
Rename-VMSan
Rename-VMSnapshot
Rename-VMSwitch
Repair-VM
Reset-VMReplicationStatistics
Reset-VMResourceMetering
Resize-VHD
Restart-VM
Restore-VMSnapshot
Resume-VM
Resume-VMReplication
Revoke-VMConnectAccess
Save-VM
Set-VHD
Set-VM
Set-VMBios
Set-VMComPort
Set-VMDvdDrive
Set-VMFibreChannelHba
Set-VMFirmware
Set-VMFloppyDiskDrive
Set-VMHardDiskDrive
Set-VMHost
Set-VMMemory
Set-VMMigrationNetwork
Set-VMNetworkAdapter
Set-VMNetworkAdapterFailoverConfiguration
Set-VmNetworkAdapterIsolation
Set-VmNetworkAdapterRoutingDomainMapping
Set-VMNetworkAdapterVlan
Set-VMProcessor
Set-VMRemoteFx3dVideoAdapter
Set-VMReplication
Set-VMReplicationAuthorizationEntry
Set-VMReplicationServer
Set-VMResourcePool
Set-VMSan
Set-VMSwitch
Set-VMSwitchExtensionPortFeature
Set-VMSwitchExtensionSwitchFeature
Start-VM
Start-VMFailover
Start-VMInitialReplication
Stop-VM
Stop-VMFailover
Stop-VMInitialReplication
Stop-VMReplication
Suspend-VM
Suspend-VMReplication
Test-VHD
Test-VMNetworkAdapter
Test-VMReplicationConnection
```

Comment: Srsly bro/sis/person, do you even Google?

Comment: While it is indeed true that the OP should really have a done at least a bit of research, an answer listing cmdlets isn't really that helpful.

Comment: A question asking for teh codez is even less helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule it isn't the job of the hypervisor to install the os. Using your powershell to configure the vm you would then start your build process, which can also be scripted. Before I started using pxe boot MDT images I had unattended iso files I would mount. As soon as the system booted it ran the install self guided. I'm guessing something like this is what you would be after.

Answer (score 1):

Creating, configuring and managing VMs can easily be done via PowerShell, as other have mentioned.

However, if you want more control on the VM lifecycle, such as creating/deploying templates and cloning disks, you should have a look at [System Center Virtual Machine Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/gg610610.aspx); its operations are, of course, completely scriptable via PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from installing from media using an unattend file, it's entirely possible, and probably faster, to configure recent versions of Windows entirely offline.  You'd create a VHD using the Hyper-V PowerShell cmdlets.  Then you'd install a Windows image in it.  Then you'd connect the VHD to a VM and boot it.

Perhaps the easiest way to do that would be to use the WIM2VHD script:

http://www.bing.com/search?q=Convert-WindowsImage.ps1%20%E2%80%94%20WIM2VHD%20for%20Windows%208%20and%20Windows%208.1&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=convert-windowsimage.ps1%20%E2%80%94%20wim2vhd%20for%20windows%208%20and%20windows%208.1&sc=0-7&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=cd83b480e637456090505eefa3fbc5f2

If you want to dig in more, the script above is constructed from primitives found in the OPK/AIK/MDT technologies:

http://www.bing.com/search?q=Deploy%20Windows%208.1%20with%20the%20Microsoft%20Deployment%20Toolkit&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=deploy%20windows%208.1%20with%20the%20microsoft%20deployment%20toolkit&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=e821766decfe449381a60f13de482664